# How to add custom webparts on a webpage without editing the page.(powershell)

Tags: web-part, powershell

Every time after deploying the WSP. Editing the page and adding all the custom webparts on every page is tiresome. Is there any easy way to add all the web parts dynamically using powershell ??

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647999/sharepoint-2013-add-web-part-to-page-using-client-side-object-model. I would recommend a feature receiver instead.

Answer (score 0):

try the script in the following link:

[How to Add WebPart to the Publishing Page using PowerShell in SharePoint 2013 - See more at: http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Add-WebPart-to-the-Publishing-Page-using-PowerShell-in-SharePoint-2013#sthash.Qb34PJms.dpuf](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Add-WebPart-to-the-Publishing-Page-using-PowerShell-in-SharePoint-2013)

I hope it helps

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)